# Webkit api for implementing finding word in page

Tags: c++, webkit, webkitgtk

Which Webkit api  is available for searching word in currently opened view(opened tab) in Webkit? 
Even an idea for implementing this would be great.

Edit:

Solution Got the api it's

```
gboolean  webkit_web_view_search_text ()  
void  webkit_web_view_select_all ()
```

Reference:
http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/webkitgtk-webkitwebview.html#webkit-web-view-search-text

Comment: a bit more clarity to the question might help. have you implemented a browser by embedding webkit nightly build ? what is meant by currently opened view ? which language is used ?

Comment: @Kiran Yeah... I realize that! Information was too little. In fact I was on mobile device.